# Create document with byte array: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromUint8Array'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, blob

I'm trying to set a byte array as a Firestore document field.

Based on suggestions elsewhere, it should be as simple as using fromUint8Array(), as below:

```
const bytes = [72, 73];
const test = firestore.Blob.fromUint8Array(
   new Uint8Array(bytes)
);
```

But I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'fromUint8Array')

I am completely new to Firebase/Firestore and I don't know where I'm going wrong, so any pointers would be much appreciated.

My set-up:

- firebase: "^9.9.2"
- import { getFirestore, serverTimestamp, collection, query, where, runTransaction, orderBy, limit,  getDocs, doc, setDoc, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-firestore.js";
- using the webhost, firestore emulators: connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);

Comment: What type exactly is `firestore`? Where does it come from?

Comment: hey Sami: const firestore = getFirestore(app);

Comment: The problem is that `firestore.Blob` is `undefined`. It has nothing to do with the byte array

Comment: yeah - that's what i'm looking into. Thanks, Bergi. Not sure why it's undefined at the moment

Comment: OK - it's seeming that .Blob mightn't be available in the modular SDK 10.7.1.. damn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blob class is not available in the modular SDK. But Bytes is:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.bytes

Swap out firestore.Blob for Bytes, and include it in your import line and it works

```
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator, Bytes } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-firestore.js";

const bytes = [72, 73];
const test = Bytes.fromUint8Array(
   new Uint8Array(bytes)
);
```